# etcdctl endpoint health --> unhealty?

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

If I run `etcdctl` it hangs. If I use `--debug=true` I see:

```
root@k8scp:~# kubectl exec -n kube-system -it etcd-k8scp sh


sh-5.1# ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --debug=true endpoint health

{"level":"warn","ts":1643546720.7707205,"logger":"client","caller":"v3/retry_interceptor.go:62","msg":"retrying of unary invoker failed","target":"etcd-endpoints://0xc0005681c0/127.0.0.1:2379","attempt":0,"error":"rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = latest balancer error: last connection error: connection closed"}
127.0.0.1:2379 is unhealthy: failed to commit proposal: context deadline exceeded
Error: unhealthy cluster
```

I know the etcd is running fine.

Why does this command fail?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by looking at the logs:

```
root@k8scp:~# kubectl logs -n kube-system etcd-k8scp 

{"level":"warn","ts":"2022-01-30T12:45:09.762Z","caller":"embed/config_logging.go:169",
"msg":"rejected connection","remote-addr":"127.0.0.1:36846","server-name":"",
"error":"tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake"}
```

The server wants TLS, but the default endpoint for `etcdctl` is localhost via `http` (not `https`).

Comment: If its in kubernetes, it most likely runs on TLS; you have to provide ca-cert, client-cert and client-key for the call to succeed, roughly `etcdctl --endpoints=https://127.0.0.1:2379 --cacert=/etc/etcd/pki/ca.pem --cert=/etc/etcd/pki/etcd.pem --key=/etc/etcd/pki/etcd-key.pem member list`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error due to whitespaces in cli, see the difference below:

```bash
kubectl -nkube-system exec -it etcd-k8s-cp -- sh -c "ETCDCTL_API=3
ETCDCTL_CACERT=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
ETCDCTL_CERT=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt
ETCDCTL_KEY=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key
etcdctl endpoint health"
# 127.0.0.1:2379 is unhealthy: failed to commit proposal
# Error: unhealthy cluster

kubectl -nkube-system exec -it etcd-k8s-cp -- sh -c "ETCDCTL_API=3 \
ETCDCTL_CACERT=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt \
ETCDCTL_CERT=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt \
ETCDCTL_KEY=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key \
etcdctl endpoint health"
# 127.0.0.1:2379 is healthy: successfully committed proposal
# Success

kubectl -nkube-system exec -it etcd-k8s-cp -- sh -c "ETCDCTL_API=3 ETCDCTL_CACERT=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt ETCDCTL_CERT=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt ETCDCTL_KEY=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key etcdctl endpoint health"
# 127.0.0.1:2379 is healthy: successfully committed proposal
# Success
```